# Madison Island Magento 1.9

Tags: rwd-theme

How to remove Madison Island from magento 1.9 and from database 
(Godaddy) / (Cpanel) / (phpmyadmin) ?
I am trying to remove default theme from magento and installing new theme but i don't know how to remove the default.
But i already install new theme on magento

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to remove a theme in Magento. It is an unconventional thought I think.

If you want to change the theme, you need to specify your new theme in your system configuration section in admin.

For this :

1. Login into admin
2. Go to `System  > Configuration`
3. Select `Design` section
4. Specify the package and theme name of your required theme over there.
5. Remove the cache.
6. You are done.